# $o(|X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)|) $ is $o(\Delta t)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

X is differentiable.

if $X'(t) \neq 0 $ , it's easy to show.

$ \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{o(|X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)|)}{|X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)|} \frac{|X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)|}{\Delta t} = 0 \cdot |X'(t)|$

But how about when $X'(t) = 0$ ?
I mean $ X(t+\Delta t)-X(t) = 0$.